# VS 2017 & Angular /w no dist or wwwroot

Tags: angular, visual-studio, webpack

I created an Angular project using VS 2017.  I used the built in Angular template.

When I run the project everything seems to work.

What I can't figure out is where the js and html files are.  The TS code must be transpiled but I don't see where it is saved as a file anywhere.  There are no files in the wwwroot and there is no dist created.

I think a lot of my confusion comes from how the newer Angular internally uses WebPack.  I used to use GULP so I knew where all my files were distributed to and how to deploy them.

I've spent all day trying to figure out where the files are, if they exist, and if they don't exist then what files do I deploy to a web server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use Angular-CLI template for visual studio you have dist folder just build it

(you can download it from here [Visual Studio MarketPlace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreyFomin.AngularCLIProjectTemplate))

otherwise if you use Default ASP.NET Core Web Application, after publish it scripts create in publish profile folder

Comment: I think I’m starting to understand. I think that during development no js files are created. That is what confused me. I think the Angular cli transposes the TS files but only in memory.  Then, as you said, the files are created only when I publish. 

This eliminates a build step that I used to do with my task runners. 

I wish this was all documented more clearly. 

Thanks for your answer.